# I'm finding a way to play mp3 file girectly taken from url in flutter

Tags: flutter

Yes, I saw some of the questions with android and javascript but I am unable to find a way to do that in a flutter. I want to play an mp3 which is directly taken from a URL. Currently, I'm using a URL Launcher which is working fine but it loads in the browser. Is there any other way to implement within flutter app?

Answer (score 2):

Use package `audioplayers 0.14.1` The documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) says "To play a Remote File, just call play with the URL (the isLocal parameter is false by default):". Following code snippet may help :

```
play() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play(url);
    if (result == 1) {
      // success
    }
  }
```

[This](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-add-music-audio-to-your-flutter-app-dcb6162c32d7) link might help. It has multiple audio players with their pros and cons.

Answer (score 2):

There are may audio plugins for flutter audio stream such as this. [Just Audio Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)

Just search in [Flutter Pub](https://pub.dev/packages?q=audio) and try other plugins. If none of them are currently working for you. Try a flutter method channel and create a native player in Java or Kotlin (a work around).